# Separating a part of the strings based on format

Tags: python, string, format

I want to give a solution for separating  part of any string based on a format link this :

```
Drop the Mic S02E16 1080p WEB x264-TBS ====> Drop the Mic S02E16


Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05 720p HDTV x264-CBFM ======> Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05


Dead of Winter S01E03 Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY ======> Dead of Winter S01E03


Saturday Night Live S44E14 John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS =====>  Saturday Night Live S44E14
```

the Incomming string is not guessing but all of theme have a format like : `"some text some text " + "S00E00" + "some text some text"` i just want to find out how i can create a format for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex seems appropriate here - search for "S" followed by some number of digits followed by "E" followed by some number of digits.

```
import re

def get_title(s):
    m = re.match(".*S\d+E\d+", s)
    if not m: raise Exception("Couldn't find S<num>E<num> substring")
    return m.group(0)

test_cases = [
    "Drop the Mic S02E16 1080p WEB x264-TBS",
    "Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05 720p HDTV x264-CBFM",
    "Dead of Winter S01E03 Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY",
    "Saturday Night Live S44E14 John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS"
]

for s in test_cases:
    print(s, "====>", get_title(s))
```

Result:

```
Drop the Mic S02E16 1080p WEB x264-TBS ====> Drop the Mic S02E16
Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05 720p HDTV x264-CBFM ====> Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05
Dead of Winter S01E03 Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY ====> Dead of Winter S01E03
Saturday Night Live S44E14 John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS ====> Saturday Night Live S44E14
```

If you need to access each part of the title individually, then you can use capturing groups:

```
import re

def get_info(s):
    m = re.match("(.*)(S\d+E\d+)(.*)", s)
    if not m: raise Exception("Couldn't find S<num>E<num> substring")
    return m.groups()

test_cases = [
    "Drop the Mic S02E16 1080p WEB x264-TBS",
    "Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05 720p HDTV x264-CBFM",
    "Dead of Winter S01E03 Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY",
    "Saturday Night Live S44E14 John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS"
]

for s in test_cases:
    title, episode_num, format_info = get_info(s)
    print(s)
    print("\tTitle:", title)
    print("\tEpisode Number:", episode_num)
    print("\tFormat Info:", format_info)
```

Result:

```
Drop the Mic S02E16 1080p WEB x264-TBS
        Title: Drop the Mic
        Episode Number: S02E16
        Format Info:  1080p WEB x264-TBS
Hughesy We Have A Problem S03E05 720p HDTV x264-CBFM
        Title: Hughesy We Have A Problem
        Episode Number: S03E05
        Format Info:  720p HDTV x264-CBFM
Dead of Winter S01E03 Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY
        Title: Dead of Winter
        Episode Number: S01E03
        Format Info:  Winters Bone 1080p WEB x264-UNDERBELLY
Saturday Night Live S44E14 John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS
        Title: Saturday Night Live
        Episode Number: S44E14
        Format Info:  John Mulaney 720p WEB x264-TBS
```